# ExtJS not loading in internet explorer

Tags: extjs4

Hi I create on page using extjs its not loading in ie.

While debugging giving this error.

SCRIPT5007: Unable to get value of the property 'events': object is null or undefined 
ext-all-debug.js, line 17621 character 15

Comment: Its loading in chrome and mozilla firefox.

Comment: version of IE browser?

Comment: which version of extjs are you using?

Comment: I am using 3.0.0 and IE9